# Using System.AccessToken to create a service endpoint

Tags: azure-devops

Currently, we use a specific username and PAT to make Azure DevOps REST API calls, but this isn't a good solution from a maintenance and fragility point of view. We'd like to use the OAuth token instead.

One case that we're running into issues is trying to generate service endpoints from our pipeline. I can check if the endpoint exists just fine from our Powershell script using:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://xxx.visualstudio.com/projectname/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview.2 -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Verbose -Debug
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use the following to create the endpoint if it doesn't exist, I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden). This is the call:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://xxx.visualstudio.com/projectname/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview.2 -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Body $RequestBody -Verbose -Debug
```

Looks like the user invoking this does not have permissions to create resources (or at least service endpoints). I'm the one running the release, but I don't believe it's my access because I am the admin on the entire organization and can do pretty much anything. I've also modified the built in Project Collection Build Service user's access on the release pipeline to have full access and still get the issue. Is what I am trying to achieve not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth Access Token is created with "Project Collection Build Service(xxx)" account, not your account, so you need to give "Project Collection Build Service(xxx)" account permission to create service endpoint.

Comment: As I said in my last paragraph, I gave the Project Collection Build Service user full permissions on the release pipeline and still encountered the issue. I did not modify the users permissions at the project or organization level, so they are whatever they are by default.

Comment: @fepiv Which permission you configure? According to your description, you configured the access on the release pipeline, not permission to create service endpoint. To configure the permission to create service endpoint, you need to add the account to Service Endpoint Creator group.

Comment: It took awhile for me to get back around to this. You are correct that I needed to add that user to Endpoint Creator group. I used your suggested configuration today and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there anyway to add the Hosted Build agents / Service accounts to the Endpoint create or administrators?  I notice that only when there is a custom pool and agent added to the project and then if that is added to the Endpoint Admin or Creator group - the Hosted Agents get an OAuth token that will work. Once the custom agent "Project Collection Build Service (xxx)" is removed, then Hosted agents no longer have access.

Comment: I was trying to get the pipeline to support doing a lookup via REST on the Service Endpoints - I have it working, however; it requires a custom agent pool / agent. Once "any" custom agent is added, then either the Hosted or Custom agent will work and get a proper OAuth2 token.  However, if there is NO custom agent - no Hosted Agent can be added to permissions ...

Comment: FYI in Azure DevOps you can find Project Collection Build Service Accounts in the team project Settings page on the Repos tab. You can set the permissions per repo.