# Azure Devops Agent doesnt have permission to create a Service Endpoint (how do you allocate permissions)

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As part of our release pipeline we're attempting to create a [service endpoint using the rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1). we're using a powershell script to call the endpoint. This script is run in a *Powershell Pipeline Task.*

[image]

To call the endpoint, we use the oAuth token [provided to the Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#communication) via the variable (`$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`)

[image]

by checking the agent configuration option:

[image]

Unfortunately, when the endpoint is called this token doesn't seem to have permission to create the service endpoint. If i hard code my own PAT, this call succeeds.

[image]

*The **Create Service Connection** task is the powershell task that runs the script our powershell function Create-ServiceConnection from module file Vsts-ServiceConnection.psm1*

**The error message is very well descriptive but the difficulty is finding how do i allocate permissions that will be provided to the Agents oAuth token?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS: Using System.AccessToken to create a service endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672413/vsts-using-system-accesstoken-to-create-a-service-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

after finding this answer [VSTS: Using System.AccessToken to create a service endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672413/vsts-using-system-accesstoken-to-create-a-service-endpoint?rq=1)

[image]

i added the permission to the "Project Collection Build Service" and it worked!

[image]