# Obtain OAuth token from Github service connection

Tags: azure-devops

I have a OAuth github service connection in Azure Devops.
I need to call the Github API through the OAuth connection established by the pipeline.

Is there any way to get a token for that purpose from the pipeline ?

For instance:

```
# How do I get the pipeline token so I can use it here.
$Token = $(MyToken)
$Headers = @{Headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([char[]]$Token));'Accept'        = 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'" } }
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.github.com/rate_limit' @Headers 
$res.resources
```

The checkout process clearly use a basic token.
How do I do the same without creating a task.

```
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepoName.extraheader
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
```

If I needed the Azure Devops token, I'd use the **System.AccessToken** variable, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672413/using-system-accesstoken-to-create-a-service-endpoint).
I kind of want this, but with a service connection instead.
(Ideally, that should work with OAuth endpoints, as per the image below and the Azure Pipelines app integration)

[image: Oauth connection]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: @DaveS Unfortunately no. And since then we moved out of Azure Pipelines to Github Actions directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerShell you can use the [VstsTaskSdk Module](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/tree/9cedd04cc64c6b899b8b7826c54ec67c4682aa28/powershell) and then use the `Get-VstsEndpoint` method.

For example:

```
$endpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name $serviceName -Require
$token = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.accessToken
```

Comment: This does not work though. Are you actually using this in one of your pipeline ?

 From one of the comment here [(https://www.locktar.nl/programming/powershell/use-azuread-powershell-cmdlets-on-vsts-agent/), it looks like the API endpoint might be only available through an API extension and not from an API hosted agent. I did an install / import of the module and did set the `$ServiceName` variable accordingly to the name of my service endpoints (Tried both the Oauth and the Azure Pipeline apps)

Comment: It does just give out a terminating error with no error message on the `Get-VsTsEndpoint` line. If I try it locally (where I am obviously not in an agent), the Get-VSTSEndpoint ask for an endpoint, credentials and data interactively. I suspect that the service connection being not available, the same interactive request is sent to the pipeline (since not available) , which in turns throw a terminating error.

Comment: @SagePourpre I use it in my PS extension, so probably you're right, it could be used only there :(